# How to avoid OVER_QUERY_LIMIT nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-maps, geolocation

I'm hitting this error every time when I want to create new place in my database, I was trying implement setTimeout() to avoid this case, but I'm not suer if I doing this properly. Any advise ?

```html
router.post("/",middleware.isLoggedIn ,upload.single("image"),function(req, res){
 
    geocoder.geocode(req.body.place.location, function(err, data){
        while(status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OVER_QUERY_LIMIT)
        {      
            setTimeout(3000);
        }  
        if ( err){   
            req.flash("error", err.message);
            console.log("error");  
            return res.redirect("back");
        }
        req.body.place.lat = data[0].latitude;
        req.body.place.lng = data[0].longitude;
    //cloudinary configuration    
    cloudinary.uploader.upload(req.file.path, function(result){
        // add cloudinary url for the image to the campground object under image property
        req.body.place.image = result.secure_url;
        // add author to campground
        req.body.place.author = {
            id: req.user._id,
            username: req.user.username
        };

        Place.create(req.body.place, function(err, newlyCreated){
            if(err){
                res.send(err);
            }else{
                res.redirect("/");
            }
        });
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Do google.maps.places.Autocomplete could be problem as well ?

Answer (score 0):

[From GOOGLE documentation concerning query limits](https://developers.google.com/maps/premium/usage-limits)

"Upon receiving a response with status code OVER_QUERY_LIMIT, your application should determine which usage limit has been exceeded. This can be done by pausing for 2 seconds and resending the same request. If status code is still OVER_QUERY_LIMIT, your application is sending too many requests per day. Otherwise, your application is sending too many requests per second."

Your first step needs to be the 2 second timeout to determine the cause. If it is too many per second, reduce until you don't get the error any more.

Cd&

Comment: I've made mistake, that status code came because of invalid api_key, thanks for response anyway :)